# Finding if dates are between a specific date range from two date variables

Tags: sql, sas

I have dataset which has a code and a code_date related to that code , I have another date field exp_date , I have to check if the dates in exp_date are between code 271 date and code 272 date , if the exp_date is between that date keep the data else remove it.

Data that I have

```
    input acct_num  code code_date exp_date ;
    DATALINES; 
    1111   271    23FEB2020  27FEB2020
    1111   272    13MAR2020  21FEB2020
    2222   271    17MAR2020  28MAY2021
    2222   271    17MAR2020  29MAY2021
    2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
    2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
    3333   271    23JUL2018  02JUN2022
    3333   272    21SEP2018  02JUN2022
    
    ;
    run;
```

Data that I want

```
    1111   271    23FEB2020  27FEB2020
    1111   272    13MAR2020  21FEB2020
    2222   271    17MAR2020  28MAY2021
    2222   271    17MAR2020  29MAY2021
    2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
    2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
```

If you can see I no longer have values for account number 3333 as no dates in exp_date is between 271 code date and 272 code date.

Comment: Even if any of the dates in exp_date comes in between the code dates ,all rows have to be kept

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group` and having `having` clauses.

Example:

The problem stated could probably use clarification.

```
data have;
  input id  code (code_date exp_date) (2*:date9.) ;
  format code_date exp_date date9.;
  datalines; 
1111   271    23FEB2020  27FEB2020
1111   272    13MAR2020  21FEB2020
2222   271    17MAR2020  28MAY2021
2222   271    17MAR2020  29MAY2021
2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
2222   272    31DEC2021  02JUN2021
3333   271    23JUL2018  02JUN2022
3333   272    21SEP2018  02JUN2022
;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select each.*
  , bounds._271min format=date9.
  , bounds._271max format=date9.
  , bounds._272min format=date9.
  , bounds._272max format=date9.
  from have as each
  join 
  (select distinct inner.id
   , min(case when code=271 then code_date else  1e12 end) as _271min
   , max(case when code=271 then code_date else -1e12 end) as _271max
   , min(case when code=272 then code_date else  1e12 end) as _272min
   , max(case when code=272 then code_date else -1e12 end) as _272max
   from have as inner
   group by inner.id
    having inner.exp_date between 
      case when _271min<_272min then _271min else _272min end
      and
      case when _271max>_272max then _271max else _272max end
  ) as bounds
  on bounds.id = each.id
  ;
```